# What is "passive data structure" in Android/Java?

Tags: java, android

From the Android developer web link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html, you can find that it says "It (Intent) is basically a passive data structure holding an abstract description of an action to be performed." But I don't understand what is "passive data structure"? Could anyone help to explain it? Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A passive data structure (opposite of *active data structure*, or *functional data structure*) is one that is managed exclusively by external threads. That is to say, it does not have some associated thread which performs operations on it.

Basically, it's like a container of information; you create it, set all its information, and it just exists to be accessed by other processes (in Android, `Activity` objects, usually). Hence, it is not actively being access (so it's not "active"), and it is not being operated on (not "functional"), so it should be considered passive.

Answer (score 3):

I think the idea is that the Intent doesn't know how to *do* the activity, it only contains the info to *describe* what needs to be done.  it's up to the receiver to actually enact the action using the Intent's information.  hence, the Intent is "passive" in regards to the resulting action.

Answer (score 0):

An Intent does not represents an action, it only represents the intentions for an action and so it only describes an action, hence its a passive data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [NIST Dictionary of Algorithms and Data Structures](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads//HTML/passiveDataStruc.html)

- **passive data structure** is one which can be only changed by external thread or processes as stated
- **active data structure** is a data structure which performs internal operation to give external behavior of another data structure

Answer (score 0):

A Passive Data Structure (PDS) is an object which just holds the data. That data is processed by some other message. You can say it is a transfer object, which is passed from one object to another object. Sometimes, in Java, POJO objects with getter/setter (or mutator) methods are considered PDS object but they are not. They breaks the rule of encapsulation and does not considered the PDS objects.

Even in Android, the Intent class just holds the data but does not process it.

Refer this link for more clarity:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_data_structure